# Changing system variable for testing purpose in ABAP

Tags: abap

I get an error on running the program: No corrosponding flights found

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uFI6.jpg)

Upon analyzing the code, I found that the program calls a BAPI:

```
BAPI_SFLIGHT_GETLIST
*"*"Lokale Schnittstelle:
*"  IMPORTING
*"     VALUE(FROMCOUNTRYKEY) LIKE  BAPISFDETA-COUNTRYFR
*"     VALUE(FROMCITY) LIKE  BAPISFDETA-CITYFROM
*"     VALUE(TOCOUNTRYKEY) LIKE  BAPISFDETA-COUNTRYTO
*"     VALUE(TOCITY) LIKE  BAPISFDETA-CITYTO
*"     VALUE(AIRLINECARRIER) LIKE  BAPISFDETA-CARRID DEFAULT SPACE
*"     VALUE(AFTERNOON) LIKE  BAPI_AUX-AFTERNOON DEFAULT SPACE
*"     VALUE(MAXREAD) LIKE  BAPI_AUX-MAXREAD DEFAULT 0
*"  EXPORTING
*"     VALUE(RETURN) LIKE  BAPIRET2 STRUCTURE  BAPIRET2
*"  TABLES
*"      FLIGHTLIST STRUCTURE  BAPISFLIST
```

The BAPI further calls a select:

```
  SELECT SFLIGHT-CARRID SFLIGHT-CONNID SFLIGHT-FLDATE
         AIRPFROM AIRPTO
         DEPTIME
         SEATSMAX SEATSOCC
         FROM SPFLI                    " connections
         INNER JOIN SFLIGHT            " flights
           ON  SPFLI~CARRID = SFLIGHT~CARRID
           AND SPFLI~CONNID = SFLIGHT~CONNID
         INNER JOIN SCITAIRP AS F      " Mapping cities to
           ON SPFLI~AIRPFROM = F~AIRPORT      " airports
         INNER JOIN SCITAIRP AS T
           ON SPFLI~AIRPTO = T~AIRPORT
         WHERE F~COUNTRY    = FROMCOUNTRYKEY    " restrictions
         AND   F~CITY       = FROMCITY
         AND   T~COUNTRY    = TOCOUNTRYKEY
         AND   T~CITY       = TOCITY
         AND   FLDATE       >= SY-DATUM        "<====================== HERE
         AND   DEPTIME      > AFTERNOON_HLP
         AND   SPFLI~CARRID IN CARRID
         ORDER BY FLDATE AIRPFROM AIRPTO.
```

The select is not able to return any data since SY-DATUM= today's date. While in the database there are no flights today.

How can i change sy-datum system field?

As a workaround for testing purpose, I tried to change fldate from sflight table in the database to today'a date, however system throws referential integrity constraint error. Is there any other work around available?

Comment: Is "regenerating the SFLIGHT demo data" an option?

Comment: Don't you have access to debug mode and permissions for changing variable's values in debug?

Comment: Well if you on a sandbox machine you can add an enhancement at the end of the badi and wright the select by your own.

Comment: Changing the value in the Debugger would be the simplest way.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are several options you can consider

1. Change the variable content in the debugger
2. List copy the example program in your own namespace and manipulate the coding the way you want.
3. Enhance the source code at `BAPI_SFLIGHT_GETLIST`

   1. open your sourcecode editor with the function module
   2. Switch to change mode
   3. call contextmenu Enhancements->Create
   4. Do whatever you want
   5. If you want to know more in details what to do you can look at this SAP docu [ABAP SourceCode Enhancements](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70ehp1/helpdata/en/a0/47e94086087e7fe10000000a1550b0/content.htm)